# Why is JMeter Result is different to User Experience Result?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

We are currently conducting performance tests on both web apps that we have, one is running within a private network and the other is accessible for all. For both apps, a single page-load of the landing page or initial page only takes between 2-3 seconds on a user POV, but when we use blaze and JMeter, the results are between 15-20 seconds. Am I missing something? The 15-20 seconds result came from the Loadtime/Sample Time in JMeter and in Elapsed column if extracted to .csv. Please help as I'm stuck.

We have tried conducting tests on multiple PCs within the office premises along with a PC remotely accessed on another site and we still get the same results. The number of thread and ramp-up period is both set to 1 to imitate a single user only.

Answer (score 0):

Where a delta exists, it is certain to mean that two different items are being timed.   It would help to understand on your front end are you timing to a standard metric, such as w3c domComplete, time to interactive, first contentful paint, some other location, and then compare where this comes into play on the drilldown on the performance tab of chrome.   Odds are that there is a lot occuring that is not visible that is being captured by Jmeter.

You might also look for other threads on here on how jmeter operates as compared to a "real browser"  There are differences which could come into play affecting your page comparisons, particularly if you have dozens/hundreds of elements that need to be downloaded to complete your page.   Also, pay attention to third party components where you do not have permission to test their servers.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 possible causees:

1. Clear your browser history, especially browser [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching). It might be the case you're getting [HTTP Status 304](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/304) for all requests in browser because responses are being returned from the browser cache and no actual requests are being made while JMeter always uses "clean" session.
2. Pay attention to `Connect Time` and `Latency` metrics as it might be the case the server response time is low but the time for network packets to travel back and forth is very high.

   > - **Connect Time**. JMeter measures the time it took to establish the connection, including SSL handshake. Note that connect time is not automatically subtracted from latency. In case of connection error, the metric will be equal to the time it took to face the error, for example in case of Timeout, it should be equal to connection timeout.
   > - **Latency**. JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte. Protocol analysers (such as Wireshark) measure the time when bytes are actually sent/received over the interface. The JMeter time should be closer to that which is experienced by a browser or other application client.

   So basically "Elapsed time = Connect Time + Latency + Server Processing Time"

In general given:

- the same machine
- [clean browser session](https://www.howtogeek.com/304218/how-to-clear-your-history-in-any-browser/)
- and [JMeter configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

you should get similar or equal timings for the same page

Comment: I tried your recommendation plus what the other forums and threads suggests, I still get the same result as compared to the actual page load. What I noticed is that blazemeter picked up a lot of samplers when opened in jmeter, I mean a lot which is 31. Each having their own sample time and if they sum up is the total sample time. Which does not equate with the actual load.

Are there any possible to ways to run those samplers in parallel?